# Can I use the extreme value theorem to prove uniform convergence of a sequence of functions on a compact interval?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

For example $f_n(x)=(1+x/n)^n$ converges pointwise on $\Bbb R$ to $f(x)=e^x$, but not uniformly because $f_n(n)\to+\infty$ and $f_n(-2n)$ has no limit.

Is it logically sound to say that the convergence is uniform on every compact $E_M=[-M,M]$ because $\lvert f_n(x)-f(x)\rvert$ is continuous on $E_M$ for all $n$, and thus attains a maximum $\left\lvert\left(1+\frac{a_n}{n}\right)^n-e^{a_n}\right\rvert$ which goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ because $a_n$ is confined in $[-M,M]$?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @TonyK No it does not. See my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is not good. Take, for example

$$f_n(x) = \begin{cases}nx & 0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{n}\\
2-nx & \frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq \frac2n\\
0& x\geq \frac2n\\
\end{cases}$$

Clearly, $f_n-f$ is a continuous function on $[0,1]$ for every $n$. It attains a maximum at $a_n$, and the maximum is confined in $[0,1]$.

However, we cannot conclude that convergence is uniform on $[0,1]$, because it is not.

---

The issue with your proof is in saying that the maximum "goes to zero" without actually *proving* that it goes to zero. You claim that it's because $a_n$ is confined on a compact interval, but as you see from my proof, that's not enough.

Comment: But in the OP's case the maximum does go to zero, for the reason mentioned (that $|a_n|\le M$).

Comment: @TonyK But in my case, $a_n = \frac1n$, and still, the maximum does not go to zero (despite the fact that $a_n\leq M$). My point is not that the maximum does not go to zero (it does), but that the method OP used to prove that is *false*.

Comment: I think the OP is claiming that this particular maximum goes to zero. Certainly the proof is not perfect if you and I have such different interpretations $-$ it could do with clarification on this point.

Comment: @TonyK The OP clearly states "a maximum [...] which goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$ because $a_n$ is confined in $[-M,M]$". He is clearly saying that the fact that the maximum goes to $0$ is a consequence of the fact that $a_n$ is confined. This implication is also, clearly, wrong. Now, OP might have proven that the maximum goes to $0$ somewhere else, but the argument he *presented* is wrong. Saying that the proof is OK, as long as you ignore the parts where it's wrong and assume OP did something correct "behind the scenes"... well that's just strange to me.

Comment: Wait, what I was saying is that the "error" goes to $0$ because since $a_n $ is confined in $[-M,M]$, $a_n/n\to0 $ and thus $(1+ a_n/n)^n-e^{a_n}\to0$ - not _merely_ because $a_n\in[-M,M] $. Is it still wrong?

Comment: @Learner Why does $\frac{a_n}{n}\to 0$ imlpy $(1+a_n/n)^n-e^{a_n}\to 0$?

Comment: @5xum: I thought it was a "given" as long as $a_n$ doesn't get arbitrarily large, via the binomial theorem. A bit like $e^{a_n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_n^k/k!$ - yes, I know it's not the same, I thought it was similarly and relatedly "innocent". Why doesn't it hold?

Comment: @Learner if its as simple as you say, why don't you try rigorously proving it?

Comment: It amounts to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a_n^k}{k!}\left(\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}-1\right)$ tends to $0$, or even the absolute series $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\lvert a_n\rvert^k}{k!}\left(1-\frac{n!}{n^k(n-k)!}\right)$ - I would be grateful if you could give me feedback on this